# How can I find a table in the whole instance?

Tags: sql-server, instance

I am trying to create a report which selects data from a table called `costomersHR`. I cannot find it as we have hundreds of databases in the instance.

How can I search for a table in the whole instance?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't know but when you get an answer that actually helps you out, you have the option of [accepting it formally](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can do so for this question as well as for any or all of [your past questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/82277/alonk?tab=questions).

Answer (score 17):

To do it through code...

1) If you can assume that this table is in the `dbo` schema.

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[costomersHR]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

2) Otherwise you could loop through all databases (and query `sys.tables` in each) with something like this code for a [more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: @Martin, i can't understand how this case statement work .. can you help me to understand it.. but yes its more than amazing query to find a object.

Comment: First of all, it checks when databases are in ONLINE state and when it's true it tries to return `OBJECT_ID` connected to table, which we are looking for.

If it returns not-null value, table called `[dbo].[costomersHR]` is found and names of databases are returned for matched rows.

Comment: @PawełTajs how this case statement retrieve list of all objects against each DB?

Comment: @AA.SC - It doesn't. It just tests for the existence of a specific object. `[dbname].[dbo].[costomersHR]` for each online database by substituting in the database name. The `OBJECT_ID` function returns `NULL` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Can i modify this query to search DB names on instance contain schema 'HR' ?

Comment: @AA.SC - yes, just use `[HR].[YourTableName]` instead of `[dbo].[costomersHR]`

Comment: i am just looking for Schema not for table

Comment: @AA.SC - Ah, in that case no then. There is a `SCHEMA_ID` function but that doesn't accept two part names or database id.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this tool [RedGate SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). It works really great.

[image]